# Marshalling Exception between infinispan on Wildfly 8 and Standalone Application

Tags: java, wildfly-8, infinispan

I'm trying to create cluster between Wildfly 8.0.2 and Standalone JAR application. Both are using same Infinispan version (6.0.2) with Embedded mode. Cache configured with distributed mode. But while starting Wildfly and then starting Standalone Application, following error was thrown,

**Stanalone Infinispan Log:**

```html
2015-09-18 17:43:47,675 INFO  [JGroupsTransport] (Proxy) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [BillingServerLoc1/ActiveCallsCluster|1] (2) [BillingServerLoc1/ActiveCallsCluster, localhost-15773]
2015-09-18 17:43:47,676 INFO  [JGroupsTransport] (Proxy) ISPN000079: Cache local address is localhost-15773, physical addresses are [131.10.20.207:7700]
2015-09-18 17:43:47,762 INFO  [CacheJmxRegistration] (Proxy) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
2015-09-18 17:43:47,824 WARN  [CommandAwareRpcDispatcher] (INT-2,ActiveCallsCluster,localhost-15773) ISPN000220: Problems un-marshalling remote command from byte buffer
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Unexpected lead byte 62
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.badLeadByte(BlockUnmarshaller.java:127)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readBlockHeader(BlockUnmarshaller.java:96)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readUnsignedByte(BlockUnmarshaller.java:258)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockUnmarshaller.readInt(BlockUnmarshaller.java:296)
        at org.infinispan.commons.util.ImmutableListCopy.readExternal(ImmutableListCopy.java:222)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1292)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:272)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ArrayExternalizers$ListArray.readObject(ArrayExternalizers.java:36)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ArrayExternalizers$ListArray.readObject(ArrayExternalizers.java:22)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable$ExternalizerAdapter.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:389)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:205)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.JBossMarshaller$ExternalizerTableProxy.readObject(JBossMarshaller.java:152)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:351)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
        at org.infinispan.distribution.ch.DefaultConsistentHash$Externalizer.readObject(DefaultConsistentHash.java:306)
        at org.infinispan.distribution.ch.DefaultConsistentHash$Externalizer.readObject(DefaultConsistentHash.java:286)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable$ExternalizerAdapter.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:389)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:205)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.JBossMarshaller$ExternalizerTableProxy.readObject(JBossMarshaller.java:152)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:351)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readParameters(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:100)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:83)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.exts.ReplicableCommandExternalizer.readObject(ReplicableCommandExternalizer.java:30)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable$ExternalizerAdapter.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:389)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.ExternalizerTable.readObject(ExternalizerTable.java:205)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.JBossMarshaller$ExternalizerTableProxy.readObject(JBossMarshaller.java:152)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:351)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
        at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
        at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller.objectFromObjectStream(AbstractJBossMarshaller.java:136)
        at org.infinispan.marshall.core.VersionAwareMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:101)
        at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.java:80)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.MarshallerAdapter.objectFromBuffer(MarshallerAdapter.java:28)
        at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.handle(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:206)
        at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.handleRequest(RequestCorrelator.java:460)
        at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receiveMessage(RequestCorrelator.java:377)
        at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receive(RequestCorrelator.java:247)
        at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher$ProtocolAdapter.up(MessageDispatcher.java:665)
        at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:708)
        at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1015)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STATE_TRANSFER.up(STATE_TRANSFER.java:178)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:165)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:381)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:370)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:1010)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:234)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.handleDataReceived(UNICAST3.java:694)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:381)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK.up(NAKACK.java:636)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.BARRIER.up(BARRIER.java:103)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:147)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL.up(FD_ALL.java:184)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:301)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2.up(MERGE2.java:209)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:379)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1399)
        at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$MyHandler.run(TP.java:1585)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: an exception which occurred:
        in object of type org.infinispan.commons.util.ImmutableListCopy
```

From log it clearly shows that, nodes can see each other. But i'm not sure why StreamCorruptedException shown. Because i've just started the applications and didnt try to put any objects in cache.

Kindly help to resolve the problem.

Thanks.

Infinispan XML:

```html
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:6.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-6.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:6.0">

   <global>
   <transport clusterName="ActiveCallsCluster">
   <properties>
   <property name="configurationFile" value="jgroups-activeCalls.xml"/>
    </properties>
     </transport>
 <asyncTransportExecutor
            factory="org.infinispan.executors.DefaultExecutorFactory">
         <properties>
            <property name="maxThreads" value="25"/>
            <!-- <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="AsyncSerializationThread"/> -->
         </properties>
      </asyncTransportExecutor>
<globalJmxStatistics enabled="false" allowDuplicateDomains="true"/>
   </global>

   <default>
        <locking useLockStriping="false"/>
       <clustering mode="distribution">
        <async/>
      </clustering>
   </default>
<namedCache name="activeCallsCache">
        <compatibility enabled="true"/>
</namedCache>
</infinispan>
```

Comment: Wildfly is designed to cluster with other Wildfly instances, so you can't do what you are requesting. Did you consider a client/server set up instead? e.g. having a client in Wildlfy talk to an Infinispan Server using the Java Hot Rod client.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño Thanks for the information shared. Since we are using embedded mode in our applications, we have tried to solve with that. we will check the possibility for using client/server mode.